# How can I capture window close event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have Ajax DHTML window. I want to redirect the page on different location when some one closed the window by clicking on cross image of window.

I have used following code to open window.

```
ajaxwin=dhtmlwindow.open("ajaxbox", "ajax", popupURL, "Error Message", "width=450px,height=200px,resize=1,scrolling=1,center=1")
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically, the event you want to bind your callback to is called *onUnload*.  Downside is that people got so damn annoying with triggering javascript pop-ups when leaving a website or closing a window, most the time it is considered 'user abuse' and blocked by most browsers (much like the javascript ability to overwrite the status bar/etc.

`<opinion>`
Welcome to the web, its a *stateless* medium. See my comment below.

Comment: I don't get what "stateless" has to do with anything here. It's not really stateless for Vivek's purposes, since he seems to be talking solely about client-based behavior here.

Comment: stateless has to do with the fact that as a developer for the web, you should not create a process that results in a non-recoverable error condition if the client looses the current state of the connection (a session) in the middle of the process (either by choice, or by network issues, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

There are two events that can help you here, [onbeforeunload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536907%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [onunload](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScript/0380__Window/windowonUnLoad.htm). The onunload event may allow you to achieve what you need to, if it is fired by the browser.

Comment: how can i use this event would you please give me some demo code according to my requirement..

Comment: Vivek: click on the links.  Sheesh.